# castle wcf facility set serviceBehavior configuration name in code

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I have several services which I want to register dynamically instead of having an entry for each in the app.config, smiliar to the following example.

```
<service name="MyService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
<endpoint name="tcpEndpoint" 
      binding="netTcpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="netTcp" 
     address="net.tcp://localhost:4321/MyService" 
    contract="MyContract.IContract" />
</service>
```

I know how I can create the endpoints dynamically, but I dont know how I can define the behaviorConfiguration on the DefaultServiceModel.

Is there a way to reuse my service behavior from the app.config?

Comment: How are you creating you endpoints dynamically? Are you using a ServiceHostFactory?

Comment: something like: WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding("netTcp")).At(url);    with netTcp I define the binding configuration, which I can modifiy in the app.config. I want to do the same with the serviceBehavior.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is add the behaviors as you define the endpoint, something like this:

WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding("netTcp")).At(url).AddExtensions(new YouBehavior())

Comment: how can I get the behavior I have defined in my app.config?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to load it from the config file directly, but you can replicate each of the behaviors in code